# Drupal 8 what is the ajax event for auto complete dropdown?

Tags: ajax

Drupal 8, what is the ajax event for auto complete dropdown? i have created form alter, there i am altering my form field that is auto complete field, so now what is the ajax event for this auto complete drop down.

change, 
select, 
keyup all are not working for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use autocompleteclose event.

```
#ajax' = array(
  'callback' =>'get_user_details',
  'event' => 'autocompleteclose',
);
```